# Did paleontologist Stan Taylor discover human footprints dated from the period of dinosaurs?

Tags: paleontology

From the article [Everything We Have Been Taught About Our Origins Is A Lie](http://www.maltanow.com.mt/?p=2927):

> ... in 1968 a palaeontologist named Stan Taylor began excavations of fossilised dinosaur footprints, discovered in the bed of the Paluxy river near Glen Rose, Texas. What he unearthed shocked and dumbfounded the scientific community. Alongside the dinosaur tracks, in exactly the same cretaceous fossilised strata, were well preserved human footprints.

The article is chock-full of fairly extraordinary claims, but that one stood out as particularly falsifiable.

Comment: This site is possibly useful in drafting an answer: http://paleo.cc/paluxy/tsite.htm

Comment: That site also talks about chemtrails with a straight face and takes multiple debunked conspiracy theories as proven facts. I feel stupider for just having browsed it for five minutes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No.  The alleged human footprints have been extensively analyzed and are most likely dinosaur tracks.  There is absolutely no evidence that they are human.  [Glen J. Kuban has performed a very thorough analysis](http://www.paleo.cc/paluxy/tsite.htm) of the site, and states

> Some of the these tracks did vaguely resemble human footprints, however, many of the tracks also showed problematic (non-human) features (discussed further below).

and goes on to clearly show that there is nothing more than a vague resemblance to human footprints.  In fact, He concludes with

> After over five years of intensive research on this issue, I have concluded that no genuine human tracks have ever been found in the Paluxy Riverbed.

Kuban persuaded John Morris of the Institute for Creation Research, who participated in some of the early claims, to visit the site with him so they could evaluate the tracks together. Based on this, Morris published [a paper](http://www.icr.org/article/paluxy-river-mystery/) which acknowledges that they are not human tracks, stating

> In view of these developments, none of the four trails at the Taylor site can today be regarded as unquestionably of human origin. The Taylor Trail appears, obviously, dinosaurian, as do two prints thought to be in the Turnage Trail. The Giant Trail has what appears to be dinosaur prints leading toward it, and some of the Ryals tracks seem to be developing claw features, also.